# draw path with hole ( android )

Tags: android, canvas, svg

Does anyone have a hint for me for the following problem ?

I would like to draw a filled path ( canvas ) which has a hole in it. 
In SVG the path definition is the follow :

```
M 100 100 L 200 100 L 200 200 L 100 200 L 100 100 z
M 125 125 L 175 125 L 175 175 L 125 175 L 125 125 z
```

I would like to draw this path ( shape ) without path subtract path ( because of specific software design )

My try with java draws me a full square without a hole. I am wondering, why an SVG viewer draws the hole with the mentoined definition and the java canvas doesn't ? where is the difference ? How can I achieve this ?

```
            Path p=new Path();
        p.moveTo(100, 100);
        p.lineTo(200,100);
        p.lineTo(200,200);
        p.lineTo(100,200);
        p.close();
        p.moveTo(150, 150);
        p.moveTo(180, 150);
        p.moveTo(180, 180);
        p.moveTo(150, 180);
        p.close();
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
```

Any hint ?

regards

Comment: In the code above, you are doing just "moveTo" for your interior square.

Comment: Yes, iagreen is right. Take out the p.close() in the middle of the path.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use `Path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD)`:

```
final Path path = new Path();
final Paint paint = new Paint();

paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

path.moveTo(100, 100);
path.lineTo(200, 100);
path.lineTo(200, 200);
path.lineTo(100, 200);
path.close();

path.moveTo(150, 150);
path.lineTo(180, 150);
path.lineTo(180, 180);
path.lineTo(150, 180);
path.close();

path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Comment: I used PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR before to achieve this, but if a texture view is layouted underneath the view with the hole, that also cut a hole into the texture view itself. This works fine in this case too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SVG determines what's inside/outside a path by using the [fill-rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties). Java also allows a winding rule to be set. With Android paths there is also a [fillType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.FillType.html) which works similarly. Perhaps you have different rules set for the java or SVG code?