# Clear Specific Area Of Canvas - Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, area

Hello i have created a canvas that i stick into an imageview of the size of my layout ! In this canvas i create lines that the end of the first is the begging of the second ! My problem is that when the final line is being created how will i be able to erase parts of this line ?

```
    final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getWidth(),layout.getHeight(),  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    final Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    textPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, textPaint);
    mView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

thank you :)

Comment: Just paint over the area you want to erase :)

Comment: @rIHaN JiTHiN paint over with what ? on the background there is an other image so i cant draw another line on top of my line to make it invisible ? if i draw a line that is transparent will it work ? and will the background picture appear too ?

Comment: Hmm.. in that case refer this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130341/drawing-holes-in-a-canvas)

Comment: You only want the last line to show, is that right? So you paint transparent lines until you get to draw the last line.

Comment: @joao2fast4u no i want to show all the line and the slowly to take it away

Comment: You want to erase the lines after drawing them?

Comment: @joao2fast4u no once the whole line has been made (which is made from many small lines ) i want to erase the small lines one by one until the is no line !

Comment: ok, starting by the last line or by the first?

Comment: @joao2fast4u by the last line ! basically i have a big line and i want slowly to vanish it :)

Comment: I think you will have to clear the canvas and draw everything over again and again, with the disappearing line having progressively lower alpha. Possible performance improvement (not sure): If your background is always the same, create two views on top of each other, so at least the background doesn't have to be continuously redrawn.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the solution you offeres is actually REALLY REALLY good ! and i think it will have a stable performance !

Comment: I haven't tested that and I don't know much about the Canvas backend...like whether the background really isn't getting redrawn by the GPU just because it's in a separate canvas. But good luck, hopefully it works.