# How can I define a transparent circle with white background in an Android drawable file?

Tags: android, android-drawable

What I have now is more like a ring. I would like to set the background outside the circle. Is that possible in xml drawable file? Thanks.
[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEjyH.png) vs
[What I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRrWP.png)

Comment: Can you attach a sample image?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no easy way to do it in drawable file.
If you want to do it in customized view/layout, you can look at the answers in [Draw a transparent circle onto a filled android canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589267/draw-a-transparent-circle-onto-a-filled-android-canvas) and [Android canvas: draw transparent circle on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947835/android-canvas-draw-transparent-circle-on-image). Both work for me.