# Cut hole in (any)layout, that shows the underneath layouts

Tags: android

What I want to achieve is this

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXgfY.png)

basically there must be 2 layers where the one on top needs to have a hole on a specific location, with a specifc radius, that can show the underneath layout. Moreover, the hole can must be able to be resized (scale animation).

The best thing I've found is a proper library (https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) but looks limited and I don't want to import a library just for that. Another solution could be to add a custom shape and add it as a background to the top Layout (the problem with that solution is that I am not able to move the shape and to set the position/size). Or I could have a canvas and draw over it but looks overkill.
Is there an easier component to I use in order to achieve this result?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947835/android-canvas-draw-transparent-circle-on-image -- might give you some ideas.