# android imageview background

Tags: android, imageview, transparency

I need to hide the extra transparent background for the camera icon that is visible beyond profile pic.

[image: UPDATED IMAGE FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING MY ISSUE]

Here is the XML code that I used.

How can I achieve this

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

            android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/girl_sample_picture" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#60000000"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCameraChangeProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your camera icon as separated file

Comment: Change your LinearLayout background color to Transparent "#00000000"

Comment: try to add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to `ic_menu_camera`

Comment: I need transparent where the actual profile pic visible,  remaining transparent should be removed

Comment: I think there is problem with image, instead of use this use another one. Use fully transparent  image not translucent image.  or either you can use default image (@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera)

Comment: Chetan was right. change background color of your LinearLayout. no need to change image.

Comment: I think this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/34702884/5345482

Answer (score 1):

Below is Transparent code list with percentage . you can add with any color like below for your case use below color code to your `LienarLayout` and try with other prefix .

```
#80000000

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

                android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/girl_sample_picture" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivCameraChangeProfilePic"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I replaced with code but, its removing the background completely and moving the camera icon to left , I need background to be semi-transparent and camera icon should be in center

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response , By considering all the above suggestions, I solved it myself by using `android:background="#60012b73"`

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

            android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/girl_sample_picture" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#60012b73"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCameraChangeProfilePic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: then time to say congrats