# Highlight circle on dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, overlay

I have an activity where I am populating a dialog, In my dialog I have to create a transparent circle which highlight the background text[image]. My problem is when dialog appears it makes the whole background as dim black , so my transparent circle also show with dim background. I am unable to highlight the circle without dim black background. Please suggest.

Comment: You can give your Dialog window a custom layout. It's well explained on the offical site.

Comment: My dialog contains custom layout , but circle transparency includes dim black background. Can u suggest me any link

Comment: Simply cut out a circle in the background image. You can use PorterDuff to do that.

Comment: using PorterDuff.Mode making my circle totaly black. I tried using DialogFragment also but no help.

Comment: `using PorterDuff.Mode making my circle totaly black` Then you are not using it correctly.

Comment: [Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947835/android-canvas-draw-transparent-circle-on-image?rq=1) It has a lot of answers.